# save hash table (with one more hash table inside) to file

Tags: c#, file, hash, hashtable, streamwriter

I am trying to read and write hashtable to file. 
I have two hashtables the first is main and the second I add to the main hashtable.
Its look like that:

```
Hashtable main = new Hashtable(); 
Hashtable x = new Hashtable(); 
main.add("123...123",x);
```

Someone have any idea what can I do ?

Comment: so the main hashtable would be key-string,value-hashtable...?

Comment: yes the key is string and the value is hashtable.

Comment: How do you want it written to a file, are you expecting a human readable file or a binary file? Also do you need to support version changes of the .NET framework or 3rd party assemblies between saving and loading or is it acceptable for the file to "break" if the assembly version changed? Lastly, is there a reason you are using `Hashtable` and not a strongly typed container like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<TInnerKey,TInnerValue>>`

Comment: You should not use `HashTable` at all.  It is effectively obsolete.  Use `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: hi Scott , 
I want to write to binary file , I dont need to support version changes of the .NET framework or 3rd party .
I used dictionary but I didnt succeed to make sub dictionary so I tied to use hashtable.

edit : I succeed create sub dictionary , now I try to write it to file.

Comment: I still cant write the main dictionary to file.